# minimal absolute value of the difference between A[i] and B[i] (array A is strictly increasing, array B is strictly decreasing)

Tags: python

Given two sequences A and B of the same length: one is strictly increasing, the other is strictly decreasing.
It is required to find an index i such that the absolute value of the difference between A[i] and B[i] is minimal. If there are several such indices, the answer is the smallest of them. The input sequences are standard Python arrays. It is guaranteed that they are of the same length. Efficiency requirements: Asymptotic complexity: no more than the power of the logarithm of the length of the input sequences.
I have implemented index lookup using the golden section method, but I am confused by the use of floating point arithmetic. Is it possible to somehow improve this algorithm so as not to use it, or can you come up with a more concise solution?

```
import random
import math
def peak(A,B):
    def f(x):
        return abs(A[x]-B[x])
    phi_inv = 1 / ((math.sqrt(5) + 1) / 2)
    def cal_x1(left,right):
        return right - (round((right-left) * phi_inv))
    def cal_x2(left,right):
        return left + (round((right-left) * phi_inv))
    left, right = 0, len(A)-1
    x1, x2 = cal_x1(left, right), cal_x2(left,right)
    while x1 < x2:
        if f(x1) > f(x2):
            left = x1
            x1 = x2
            x2 = cal_x1(x1,right)
        else:
            right = x2
            x2 = x1
            x1 = cal_x2(left,x2)
    if x1 > 1 and f(x1-2) <= f(x1-1): return x1-2
    if x1+2 < len(A) and f(x1+2) < f(x1+1): return x1+2
    if x1 > 0 and f(x1-1) <= f(x1): return x1-1
    if x1+1 < len(A) and f(x1+1) < f(x1): return x1+1
    return x1

#value check
def make_arr(inv):
    x = set()
    while len(x) != 1000:
        x.add(random.randint(-10000,10000))
    x = sorted(list(x),reverse = inv)
    return x

x = make_arr(0)
y = make_arr(1)
needle = 1000000
c = 0
for i in range(1000):
    if abs(x[i]-y[i]) < needle:
        c = i
        needle = abs(x[i]-y[i])
print(c)
print(peak(x,y))
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having with using float?

Comment: Seems like a question better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I just don’t really want to use it, my question is rather whether there is a more correct solution for this task, so that its use does not arise

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), please review what is [on topic for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @АндрейС. Unlike some other commenters, I’m not strictly of the opinion that this question doesn’t belong on stackoverflow, but “I just don’t want to use it” isn’t a reason I can understand. I’m gonna vote to close. When you actually know the problem with this code, vote to reopen.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar 
I'm sorry for not explaining the reason. Do not use floating point arithmetic in solving is the teacher's requirement

Comment: This is a completely valid programming question. It could possibly be worded better to reflect that but I think closing it is the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach**

The poster asks about alternative, simpler solutions to posted code.

The problem is a variant of [Leetcode Problem 852](https://leetcode.com/problems/peak-index-in-a-mountain-array/), where the goal is to find the peak index in a moutain array. We convert to a peak, rather than min, by computing the negative of the abolute difference.  Our aproach is to modify this [Python solution](https://walkccc.me/LeetCode/problems/0852/) to the Leetcode problem.

**Code**

```
def binary_search(x, y):
    ''' Mod of https://walkccc.me/LeetCode/problems/0852/ to use function'''
    def f(m):
        ' Absoute value of difference at index m of two arrays '
        return -abs(x[m] - y[m])    # Make negative so we are looking for a peak
            
    # peak using binary search
    l = 0
    r = len(arr) - 1

    while l < r:
      m = (l + r) // 2
      if f(m) < f(m + 1):    # check if increasing
        l = m + 1
      else:
        r = m                 # was decreasing

    return l
```

**Test**

```
def linear_search(A, B):
    ' Linear Search Method '
    values = [abs(ai-bi) for ai, bi in zip(A, B)]
    return values.index(min(values))     # linear search
    
def make_arr(inv):
    random.seed(10)    # added so we can repeat with the same data
    x = set()
    while len(x) != 1000:
        x.add(random.randint(-10000,10000))
    x = sorted(list(x),reverse = inv)
    return x


# Create data
x = make_arr(0)
y = make_arr(1)

# Run search methods
print(f'Linear Search Solution {linear_search(x, y)}')
print(f'Golden Section Search Solution {peak(x, y)}') # posted code
print(f'Binary Search Solution {binary_search(x, y)}')
```

**Output**

```
Linear Search Solution 499
Golden Section Search Solution 499
Binary Search Solution 499
```